# Azure Function modifies queue message's ISO 8601 UTC DateTime format to Local DateTime format

Tags: c#, azure-functions, datetime-format, azure-storage-queues

## Problem

DateTime format changes from 2019-04-09T11:43:11Z to 2019-04-09T11:43:11+00:0 of my queue message.

## Details

Consider two azure functions **F1** and **F2**. **F1** enqueues a message in `f2-queue`.

Consider the following classes for understanding the preparation of a message:

```
public class MyRequest
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public object Obj {get; set;}
}

public Class MyMessage
{
    public DateTime UpdatedDate {get; set;}
}
```

I am using ADO.NET for reading from the database.

```
myMessage.UpdatedDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(Convert.ToDateTime(reader["Updated_Date"]), DateTimeKind.Utc);

myRequest.Obj = myMessage;
```

I serialize `myRequest` using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`. The serialized object has datetime as **2019-04-09T11:43:11Z**. I enqueue `myRequest` in `f2-queue`.

**F2** is a queue triggered **azure function**.

```
[FunctionName("F2")]
        public static async Task Run([QueueTrigger("f2-queue", Connection = "")]MyRequest myRequest, ILogger log)
```

Here in myRequest the DateTime format of `UpdatedDate` changes to **2019-04-09T11:43:11+00:00**.

## Things I tried

- Placed a DateTime property in `MyRequest` itself and stored DateTime.UtcNow in it. DateTime format does not change in this case.
- It appears that +00:00 changes according to the time zone set in the machine the code is running on.
- Originally was using `DateTime.TryParse(reader["Updated_Date"].ToString(), out DateTime lastUpdatedDate)` and noticed the `DateTime.Kind` was **Unspecified**. Changed to the above-mentioned approach. The DateTime.Kind is **Utc** now but DateTime format is still changing.
- Instead of assigning the value from the database, assigned DateTime.UtcNow. The format still changes. It appears there is no problem in assigning the value.
- Looked into the queue using **Storage Explorer**. The message itself has a perfectly fine DateTime format.

Comment: When you say "... Here in myRequest the DateTime format of UpdatedDate changes..." what specifically do you mean?  How are you evaluating it? You didn't show what your function does, so without some code showing how you see that result it's going to be tough to answer completely.

Comment: Also you mention `F1` and `F2`, but you only really talk about `F2`.  Is there some relationship with `F1` that we should be considering?

Comment: 1. DateTime format is ISO 8601 UTC Date Format in queue (verifed using Storage Explorer).
2. When F2 dequeues the message and desearlizes it to `MyRequest` the format changes to Local DateTime format. Verified using Visual Studio Watch window.

Comment: F1 is just simply preparing the message as stated in Details heading and enqueues the message in `f2-queue`.

Comment: Have you by chance altered the `JsonSerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling` elsewhere in your code?  The default `RoundtripKind` setting is what controls this, and should work for your use case.

Comment: Also, is there a reason this creates a problem for you?  For example, does the `.Kind` of `UpdatedDate` change to `Local`?  Or is it just that you see `+00:00` in the visual studio watch window (which shouldn't matter really).

Comment: 1. Nope. No change. It's a simple azure function.
2. I need to send this to my front-end app using signalr. My front-end uses the standard ISO 8601 Utc DateTime format. I need to send this message to my front-end using Azure SignalR. Currently, SignalR is also sending it in `+00:00` format because of the stated situation.

Comment: `+00:00` is also ISO 8601 compliant.  They mean almost the same thing, just they carry different semantics, and are interpreted by `DateTime.Parse` differently when `DateTimeStyles.RoundTripKind` is used.  In most cases, it won't make a difference, even on the front-end.  In fact, you might consider just using `DateTimeOffset` types instead.

Comment: I need to do some more investigation with Azure Function's specific behavior behavior before I answer this further.

Comment: 1. Yes, I know that it's ISO 8601 compliant. I mean the ISO 8601 "Utc DateTime format" is required. The front-end expects the same format.
2. Thanks. Kindly let me know if you have any further questions. Please note the 1st and 4th point under the "Things I tried" heading. They might be useful.

Comment: @MattJohnson I have handled it on the front-end since both semantics are ISO compliant but I would really appreciate an answer to understand what is going on. Thanks

Comment: Is this in Functions v1 or v2? (aka .NET 4.x or .NET Core)

Comment: @SamaraSoucy-MSFT F1 is in v1 and F2 is in v2.

Answer (score 0):

It does appear to be because of how Newtonsoft serializes DateTimes when Kind is set to Utc vs. Local. In order to change this serverside you cane use a DateFormatString setting to override the defaults.

I tested it using a console app, but the behavior should be the same within a Function. The WebJob underlying the Functions project is based on a console app.

```
namespace ConsoleApp8
{   
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ"
            };

            Console.WriteLine($"DateTime.Now: {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DateTime.Now)}, DateTime.Now Kind: {DateTime.Now.Kind}");
            Console.WriteLine($"DateTime.UtcNow: {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DateTime.UtcNow)}, DateTime.UtcNow Kind: {DateTime.UtcNow.Kind}");
            Console.WriteLine($"DateTime.Now with formatting: {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DateTime.Now, serializerSettings)}, DateTime.Now Kind: {DateTime.Now.Kind}");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The code outputs the following:

> DateTime.Now: "2019-04-16T10:53:54.6557713-04:00", DateTime.Now Kind: Local
>
> DateTime.UtcNow: "2019-04-16T14:53:54.9357612Z", DateTime.UtcNow Kind: Utc
>
> DateTime.Now with formatting: "2019-04-16T10:53:54Z", DateTime.Now Kind: Local